# mySql new rows can only be searched with LIKE, has anyone had this before?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos

A bit of background
I'm running mySQL on a mac
I have a few databases setup that have been working okay
I have recently created a new table from a sqlDump from another server.
I am having an issue with new rows that equal = a value that I know exists

e.g. Table setup

id=1 name='dave' - already exists in database

**id=2 name='john' - I add a new row**

Following are the sql I tried with results...

```
Select * from tablename where id=1 -- I get the correct Dave result.

Select * from tablename where `name` = 'dave' -- I get the correct Dave result.

Select * from tablename where id=2 -- I get the correct John result.

Select * from tablename where `name` like 'joh%' -- I get the correct John result.

Select * from tablename where `name` = 'john' -- (No result!) eek!
```

Anyone seen this before? it's in the database but a direct match on the *name* field is not yielding a result.

Thanks in advance 
M

Comment: Could you try `Select '*' + name + '*' from tablename`and look for trailing characters?

Comment: What's the result of Select *,char_length(name) from tablename where name like 'joh%' ?

Comment: try using the TRIM. Mayb there is a space after the end of string in the new inserted rows.

Comment: Three comments all thinking alike. We should get together for a drink...

Comment: Any particular reason you have the column name "name" in quotes in your query?  Aren't you then comparing two string constants?  If that's not it, maybe look for some special characters embedded in your data.

Comment: How is the `name` column defined?

Comment: @Marvo - these are backticks, not quotes. If it were quotes the other queries should not work either

Comment: Is it in the database as `John` or `JOHN` instead of `john`? Like makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility: there could be a trailing space after 'john' in the name column.

One way to check that:

```
select `name`,char_length(`name`), char_length('john')
from tablename 
where id = 2
```

Comment: Well you can all have a drink :) it seems that the value was 1 character longer than it should have been, I going to blame Sequel Pro for that as I only keyed it in directly. I'll be more careful in future

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to not have to deal with that problem would be to trim your input (if you don't expect to ever have preceding or trailing white space.

In that case you could have a query like:

```
Select * from tablename where trim(`name`) = trim('john')
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments on your question, that it is most likely a hidden space or something similar.  If you include the column definitions so we can check the data that your using with the types we could help more.  Remove the entry and and retry with a different name other than john and see if you can replicate the problem.